# Copy artifacts from other job only if there is new version of file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, master-slave

We have a master and two slaves. 
On Master there is a job which checks if there is new version on Nexus and if yes downloads latest jar and updates latest version (i.e. xxx-0.012.jar) in text file VERSION.TXT. (It is possible to access nexus only from master).

We need to run downloaded jar on **slaves** so we need to copy it from master.

We have a job which triggers few other jobs: 
1)CHECK_LATEST_JAR: job which runs on master and checks if there is new version of jar on nexus, downloads it.
2)GET_JAR_TO_SLAVE: job which runs on slaves and should copy latest jar from master
3)RUN_JAR:  job which gets latest jar name from file VERSION.TXT and runs jar with such name.

In CHECK_LATEST_JAR  if newer version is found on nexus we download it to workspace and archive artifacts (jar + text file with latest version).

Now in GET_JAR_TO_SLAVE we wanted to use "Copy artifacts from another job" plugin - but here we need to add a condition to run this step only if there is newer version as if there are no artifacts in CHECK_LATEST_JAR this job fails..

Is there a way to compare file which is located on master with file which is located on slave?
Tried to use conditional step with groovy script - but cannot figure out how to tell it to access file on master if job runs on slave.

Just came across FSTrigger plugin which probably can be used - but same problem here how to tell it to monitor file VERSION.TXT on master and if there is a change to run job on slave.

would be grateful for  any ideas how we can achieve our goal.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found plugin [Copy Data to Workspace](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Data+To+Workspace+Plugin) and used it to copy file containing latest version from folder on Master to workspace of job running on one of slaves.
After that we compare content of files using [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) strings comparison with Token macro and if files content is different we copy artifacts of the job where jar is downloaded.
[image: files content comparison]